# Android Studio Hello World Error

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Just downloaded Android Studio.  To the best of my knowledge, I added the recommended SDK tools and support libraries.  When I try building the basic Hello World app, I receive the following gradle build error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\rgalanos\Desktop\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml: Error: org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl

I haven't written any code, so it seems to be a configuration error.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your styles as well as gradle files?Seems to me there is problem with that

Comment: Could you include the source of the Hello World app?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](http://javaant.com/hello-world-using-android-studio-1-0/#.VPcPebOUc5Q) , which explain step by step process - how to run hello world in android studio.